# Crystal Reports: Display date range (month, first day of month, year to month, last day, year) based on field value

Tags: crystal-reports, date-range

I need to display a date range based on the month before a date in a field.   For example, if the date value `(DOCDATE)` is `6/6/18`, I'd like the range to display as:

`5/1/18 to 5/31/18`

I was able to use `LASTFULLMONTH` with minimum and maximum constraints and it works fine for records in the current month, but I need to use `DOCDATE` as a control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with the following formulas.

Note the formula names, because they are partly dependent on each other.

**{@prevMonth}**

Gets the previous month by subtracting one month from `{@DOCDATE}`

```
DateAdd("m", -1, {@DOCDATE})
```

**{@startDate}**

Gets the start-date (first day of previous month) by creating a new date from the year and month of `{@prevMonth}` and day `1`.

```
Date(Year({@prevMonth}), Month({@prevMonth}), 1)
```

**{@endDate}**

Gets the end-date (Last day of previous month) by creating a new date from the year and month of `{@DOCDATE}` and day `1`, minus one day

```
Date(DateAdd("d", -1, Date(Year({@DOCDATE}), Month({@DOCDATE}), 1)))
```

**{@displayRange}**

Shows the range.

```
CStr({@startDate}) & " to " & CStr({@endDate})
```

Comment: Thanks for the input!  Would you mind putting the full formula together so I can check it out?   I've tried and it keeps throwing errors.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by putting the complete formula together? There are 4 formulas and you need them all. You also have to replace `{@DOCDATE}` with the corresponding database field.

Comment: I'm pretty new to writing formulas in CR, so might be missing some obvious things.    I pasted the following formula into my report and checked it for errors and it's saying it doesn't recognize @prevMonth as a field name.

DateAdd("m", -1, {SOP10100.DOCDATE}) &

Date(Year({@prevMonth}), Month({@prevMonth}), 1)

Date(DateAdd("d", -1, Date(Year({SOP10100.DOCDATE}), Month({SOP10100.DOCDATE}), 1)))
CStr({@startDate}) & " to " & CStr({@endDate})

Comment: That won't work. You have to create four separate formulas. Name it like mentioned above. So the first formula name would be `prevMonth` with the content `DateAdd("m", -1, {SOP10100.DOCDATE}).`; the second formula name would be `startDate`...and so on. If you use a formula within another formula then Crystal Reports expects the format {@FORMULANAME}.

Comment: No problem, glad to help.